# ExpandableListAdapter - How to handle getChildrenCount?

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

Let me start by saying that I don't understand `getChildrenCount`, and by that I mean, it doesn't really act the way the documentation suggests.

To start with, I had:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    Log.i("LL", "Picking list size for selected component: " + ((LoadList)parentItems.get(groupPosition)).getPickingList().size());
    return ((LoadList)parentItems.get(groupPosition)).getPickingList().size();
}
```

Which when output to LogCat stated that the `.size()` returned was 26 children, which is exactly what I'm expecting. Yet on the device, the child items would go on (seemingly) forever...? We're talking thousands of children?!

So, for a test I changed it to:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    Log.i("LL", "Picking list size for selected component: " + ((LoadList)parentItems.get(groupPosition)).getPickingList().size());
    //return ((LoadList)parentItems.get(groupPosition)).getPickingList().size();
    return 1;
}
```

Which now displays/reports 26 children, on both device and LogCat. Marvellous! But why?

According to the documentation:

```
public abstract int getChildrenCount (int groupPosition)

Added in API level 1
Gets the number of children in a specified group.

Parameters
groupPosition   the position of the group for which the children count should be returned
Returns
the children count in the specified group
```

My question is simple... What is going on? I thought that I'd have to manually return the size     depending on my array adapter data, but according to my tests, it works correctly if you specify a     completely random value, rather than the actual? Or do I not have to override at all, and just let the OS handle it?

Answer (score 0):

The getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) is work like getCount() of simple list view the difference is that "getChilderenCount" will return number of children under the particular group which position is pass in the method.

Please have look on provided adapter example

```
public class CustomExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mQuestionArray = null;
    private String[] mOptionArray = null;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1;

    public CustomExpandableAdapter(Context context, String[] questionArray, String[][] optionArray) {
        mQuestionArray = questionArray;
        optionArray = optionArray;
        mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mQuestionArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mOptionArray[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mQuestionArray[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mOptionArray[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.faq_header_text_layout, null);
            headerViewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(headerViewHolder);
        }
        headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        headerViewHolder.mGroupHeader.setText(mQuestionArray[groupPosition]);
//        headerViewHolder.mGroupHeader.setTextSize(mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_smallest));

        if (mSelectedPosition != -1 && mSelectedPosition == groupPosition) {
            headerViewHolder.mGroupHeader.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_info_app));
        } else {
            headerViewHolder.mGroupHeader.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChildViewHolder childViewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.faq_textview_layout, null);
            childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(childViewHolder);
        }
        childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        childViewHolder.mChildTitle.setText(mOptionArray[groupPosition][childPosition]);
//        childViewHolder.mChildTitle.setTextSize(mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_smallest));
        childViewHolder.mChildTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        childViewHolder.mChildTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    private static class HeaderViewHolder {
        final TextView mGroupHeader;

        private HeaderViewHolder(View group) {
            mGroupHeader = (TextView) group.findViewById(R.id.txv_faq_header_text_layout);
        }
    }

    private static class ChildViewHolder {
        final TextView mChildTitle;

        private ChildViewHolder(View group) {
            mChildTitle = (TextView) group.findViewById(R.id.txv_faq_textview_layout);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        if (observer != null) {
            super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
        }
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int selectedPosition) {
        mSelectedPosition = selectedPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how it's supposed to work, but that's not what I'm seeing at all. In fact, my setting it to return 1, has fixed all my issues, but I'd like to know why this is the case, as it completely contradicts the documentation? :(

Comment: Documentation of android is define it very clear and absolute correct may be you are taking it in wrong way.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but I fail to see how my original code: return ((LoadList)parentItems.get(groupPosition)).getPickingList().size(); - is wrong, as it does exactly the same as yours, just via a List of objects, rather than a string array. I'm more than happy to be proved wrong and pointed in the correct direction, but I can't un-see my own tests. ;)